# How to migrate tfs web extension data?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I'm developing a web extension in on-premises TFS 2017U3.

It uses the [ExtensionDataService](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/vss/sdk/services/extensiondata/extensiondataservice) to store data.

Normally, we're not supposed to manipulate tfs data directly via database script, and I assume that applies to the Extension.tbl* tables as well. 
I've searched without success for a tool to help manipulate this data, for purposes such as migrating data across environments, or scripting initial load, etc.

I also found this [VSTS SyncMigrator](http://vsts-bulk-editor.readthedocs.io) but as far as I can tell it doesn't handle extension data.

Should we just build our own tool to do this?

Comment: Do you only want to migrate extension data? Or you want to migrate the whole TFS?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT  Just the extension data, per extension.

Comment: Currently, there is no way/tool to migrate extension data only. You could vote the User Voice at website below: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/33538582-provide-api-or-tool-to-migrate-extension-data-in-t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my knowledge, there is no way/tool to migrate extension data only. You could migrate the whole TFS by checking the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/move-across-domains

Meanwhile, I have submitted a User Voice at website below, you can vote it:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/33538582-provide-api-or-tool-to-migrate-extension-data-in-t

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a quick command-line interface using [vsts-node-api](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-node-api).